# Increase transfer speed of TCP socket in java /android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, wifi-direct

I am developing wifi direct based file transfer application. I can see that the transfer speed using TCP socket is not satisfactory. The speed is normally 1Mbps. Whenever I analyze the data transfer graph, I can see a lot of spikes and many seconds are with no data transfer at all. I know the transfer speed should be much higher (may be 20-30Mbps) 
Please help me in increasing the transfer speed. 
The serversocket that accepts the connection is

```
private void serverTask() {
        Log.v(TAG, "server task");
        try {
            serverRunning = true;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(
                    DeviceDetailFragment.PORT);
            serverSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(TCP_BUFFER_SIZE);


            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            BufferedInputStream inputstream = new BufferedInputStream(
                    client.getInputStream());
            // new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream(), 8 * 1024);
            BufferedReader bufferedStream = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputstream));


                fileName = bufferedStream.readLine();
                fileSizeInBytes = bufferedStream.readLine();
                fileMime = bufferedStream.readLine();

                f = new File(Globals.fileSavingLocation + fileName);

                File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                if (!dirs.exists())
                    dirs.mkdirs();

                if (f.exists()) {
                    f.delete();
                }

                f.createNewFile();

        IOUtils.copy(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));


                serverSocket.close();
            }
            isSuccessful = true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            isSuccessful = false;
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());

        }
        serverRunning = false;

    }
```

And the client that sends the data has following code:

```
 private void clientTask(Intent intent) {
            String fileUri = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_FILE_PATH);
            String host = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_ADDRESS);
            String fileName = intent.getExtras().getString(FILE_NAME);
            String fileMimeType = intent.getExtras().getString(FILE_MIME_TYPE);
            final long sizeInBytes = intent.getExtras().getLong(FILE_SIZE);
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            int port = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_PORT);

            try {
                socket.setSendBufferSize(TCP_BUFFER_SIZE);
                socket.bind(null);
                socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)),
                        SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                ContentResolver cr = FileTransferService.this
                        .getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                InputStream is = null;

                BufferedWriter bufferStream = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(stream));


                bufferStream.write(fileName);
                bufferStream.newLine();
                bufferStream.flush();
                bufferStream.write(String.valueOf(sizeInBytes));
                bufferStream.newLine();
                bufferStream.flush();

                bufferStream.write(fileMimeType);
                bufferStream.newLine();
                bufferStream.flush();


                try {

                    is = new BufferedInputStream(cr.openInputStream(Uri
                            .parse(fileUri)));

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    isSuccessful = false;

                }
 IOUtils.copy(is, stream);


                isSuccessful = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                isSuccessful = false;
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    if (socket.isConnected()) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // Give up
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The value of `TCP_BUFFER_SIZE` is set to `1024*512`.

I have tried a lot altering the value of TCP_BUFFER_SIZE but with no luck. I replaced my implementation of copying stream by  Apache Commons IOUtils. 
Help me out

Update:
Please see the following transfer graph
[image: Graph of transfer speed]

Comment: Do you really need to flush you buffer so often, the whole point of buffering is to reduce the number of system calls/flushes made?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have removed those flushes. However, it didnt help me out as it was just 2-3 calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are overloading the buffer, from the [setReceiveBufferSize() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReceiveBufferSize%28int%29)

> It is possible to change the value subsequently, by calling
>   Socket.setReceiveBufferSize(int). However, if the application wishes
>   to allow a receive window larger than 64K bytes, as defined by RFC1323
>   then the proposed value must be set in the ServerSocket before it is
>   bound to a local address. This implies, that the ServerSocket must be
>   created with the no-argument constructor, then setReceiveBufferSize()
>   must be called and lastly the ServerSocket is bound to an address by
>   calling bind().

Comment: Thank you so much for pinpointing.I corrected my code as per your suggestion. Now the speed is 2-3 Mbps with TCP_BUFFER_SIZE=1024*1024. But I believe, the speed can still be much more faster. Your further help will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a simple data transfer using a plain Socket without using files.

Have a simple server which sends 100 MB of empty data when you connect.  Have the client read that data as fast as it can a report the throughput it got.  On the same machine you should see over 100 MB/s easily.  Once this gives a good number try it on an android client.